# EditText in ListView need adjustResize but have losing focus bug

Tags: java, android, listview, android-edittext

I am having trouble with `EditText` in `ListView`.

`EditText` always loses focus. I have fixed this with `windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` but now soft keyboard cover input field => I need adjustResize but I will have the lost focus bug again.

Any ideas?

I create simple test project which have `ListView` on layout, in `onCreate` I initialize `ListView`and set BaseAdapter which have override method `getView()` and `getCount()`

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    EditText editText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    editText.setText("" + position);
    return v;
}
```

`list_item` layout contain `EditText` in `LinearLayout`.

Need push this test project on github?

Comment: seeing the sample code might help

Comment: Is Edittext meant to be used with ListView? ListView is designed to show thousands of item in list.